# dc.js charts with 2 different datasets and one chart updating the other

Tags: dc.js

I'm trying to connect 2 different charts with both different datasets with dc.js.

The first donut chart should serve as a filter for the line chart but I haven't found how to get the connection between the two.

I would prefer not to join these data sets as the might get large and joining does not make too much sense.

I tried to catch the selected items and filter them in the line chart

```
 sobRingChart.on('filtered', function(chart) {
   PUchart.filter(null)
   .filter(chart.filters());
   dc.redrawAll()
});
```

Example
http://jsfiddle.net/yccu/qBr7y/32/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the right idea, it's just a data mismatch.

The important thing to understand is that all filtering in crossfilter happens through the dimension objects. The value you filter needs to be compatible with the dimension you filter on.

Therefore since your line chart is time-based, you won't be able to filter it by `Source`. You'll need to set up another dimension to do that:

```
var sourceDim2 = spendData2.dimension(function(d) { return d.Source; })
```

Then filter that dimension instead of the line chart:

```
 sobRingChart.on('filtered', function(chart) {
   if(chart.filters().length)
     sourceDim2.filterFunction(function(k) {
       return chart.filters().indexOf(k) !== -1;
     });
   else sourceDim2.filter(null);
   dc.redrawAll()
 });
```

This is only complicated because it has to handle filtering on multiple values (when more than one slice of the ring chart is selected). Crossfilter doesn't make that simple, probably because it's not all that efficient. (Not that it usually matters.)

So we need to see if there are any filters. If there are, we set a filter function which looks to see if the currently considered key is in `chart.filters()`. If not, we call `.filter(null)` to clear the filter.

Comment: You saved my weekend Gordon thanks!! working link http://jsfiddle.net/yccu/qBr7y/33/

Answer (score 0):

Excelent! I've updated @YCuvelie example with little modification in D3 instructions, **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/qBr7y/126/)** it is the working example with D3.V5

instead of `d3.scale.linear()` used `d3.scaleLinear()` and included the latest version of [D3](https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js)